# What does telling Whirlwind about Vessel Town affect?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-4

On my way back to Tharsis after discovering Vessel Town, I rushed through the dialogue so I could talk to the Count. On accident, I clicked "Yes" when given the option to tell Whirlwind about Vessel Town. Does this affect the story later on? I received a Medica II, which I hardly believe is worth any possible future trouble.

Comment: From my own experience in having told him, there doesn't seem to be any real impact beyond the Medica II. Definitely doesn't get you any trouble, that's for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I did another run and from what I can see, there isn't any impact beyond getting a Medica II for telling him. The story is playing out the same way and I haven't encountered any noticeable differences.